# how to open a solution in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net, projects-and-solutions

I have a website which was created by someone; now I am trying to open it.

My doubt is will that project contain a solution? Within Visual Studio, I am trying to open through the open website option, but I didn't find a solution.

Is that right way? How best can I open a website with Visual Studio?

Comment: what are you trying to open? `http://example.com`, a local intranet site, a .sln file, or a Visual Studio Web Site project? You mentioned "trying to open through the open website option" -- edit your question and post a screenshot of that dialog box and the values you're using.

Comment: @Camp..final goal is..to know which files contains solutions.. is website project contains solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Projects do not contain solutions. Solutions are made up of one or multiple projects.
2. In case of a single website, you dont even need a solution, you can open up the website directly by the File --> Open Website option and pointing that to the folder containing the website

Answer (score 1):

There exist two different types of projects: web application and web sites. If the directory with the project does not contain a project file (*.csproj or *.vbproj) it is probably a web site. You can check this when you open an .aspx file. In the @Page tag you will see the attribute codefile whereas web application use the attribute codebehind. 
Web Sites you open with open web site. Any file in the directory belongs to the project unless it has the file extension *.excluded.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That will work if all you want to do edit the site's files directly.  If you're looking for the ASP.Net or MVC solution that was used to create the site though, then this won't work.

Comment: @Mihir: You can't.  Unless you have access to the source code somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a website as a solution unless you have explicit access to the source code. When a ASP.NET site is published, the actual solution is no longer available to the public and all you get is the HTML representation (client-side) rather than the source (server-side).

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a web/windows project you will not get solution file. It will be available only in websites. And also if you publish that website you will not get solution file. So be sure that Its a website and not published.